# How to create AWS CDK Kubernetes Manifest with array of object? (Dotnet)

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-cdk

So I'm creating kubernetes cluster with dotnet aws cdk.

Now I want to automatic create some kubernetes manifest in the cluster.

Based on AWS doc, manifest object should be created with `Dictionary<string,Object>`

However some yaml manifest contain array of object value, which contain a duplicate key.

Example:

```
   AllowedRegions:
     - key: key1
       value: val1
     - key: key2
       value: val2
```

How to represent above dictionary object?

I have try to use plain string but the object is not in array format which causing deployment error.

Aws doc reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/dotnet/api/Amazon.CDK.AWS.EKS.KubernetesManifest.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it resolved. Using

> Dictionary<string,object>[]

```
"AllowedRegions", new Dictionary<string, Object>[]
                    {
                        new()
                        {
                            { "key", "key1" },
                            { "value", "value1" }
                        },
                        new()
                        {
                            { "key", "key2" },
                            { "value", "value2" }
                        }
                    }
```